# Jquery Show just one Item by the same class after click-event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scripting

i am new in scripting Jquery/Javascript and actually i've some struggle.
How can i show one item by the same class without affect the other items?

My code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.embedContainer > .myPosterImage').on('click', function() {
    $('.embedContainer > .myPosterImage').hide();
    $('.embedContainer > embed').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="embedContainer">
  <img class="myPosterImage" src="img/websites/01_documentation.jpg" data-original="img/websites/full/01_full.jpg" />
  <embed src="img/websites/Concept.pdf" width="563.41" height="375.98"></embed>
</div>

<div class="embedContainer">
  <img class="myPosterImage" src="img/websites/01_documentation.jpg" data-original="img/websites/full/01_full.jpg" />
  <embed src="img/websites/Concept.pdf" width="563.41" height="375.98"></embed>

</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `$(this)` to navigate relative to the element you clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line will hide all of them, which may be what you want to do (if you want to collapse all and expand the clicked one, for example):

```
$('.embedContainer > .myPosterImage').hide();
```

But as you've found, this second line will also *show* all of them:

```
$('.embedContainer > embed').show();
```

What you can do is traverse the DOM starting from the element which was clicked (`this` within the click event handler).  In this case you'd traverse up the DOM (using `closest()` for example) to a common parent element and then back down (using `find()` for example) to the target element.

Something like this:

```
$(this).closest('.embedContainer').find('embed').show();
```